# Is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: python, enumerate

Is there another way of checking if something is first?

I've been using `for i,f in enumerate(read_files)` where I enumerate a list of files, and use an if statement to check if i==0. I'm curious is there is a different (better, faster, less typed) way to do this?

```
read_files = glob.glob("post_stats_*.tsv") 
with open("result.tsv", "w") as outfile: 
    for i,f in enumerate(read_files): 
        with open(f, "r") as infile: 
            metric_name = (f.strip(".tsv").split("_")[2]) 
            if i == 0: 
                outfile.write(metric_name.upper() + "\n" + infile.read()) 
            else: 
                outfile.write("\n" + metric_name.upper() + "\n" + infile.read())
```

Comment: Since your code already works, the best SE to post this on is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Cool, will do.

Comment: Do you only need that `if` to avoid starting the output file with an empty line?

Comment: @TimPietzcker That is correct

Comment: Please use a more informative title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems the only use of the `if` is to avoid a blank line at the start of the output file, how about putting the blank line *after* the file's contents? That will lead to a blank line at the end of the file where it's unlikely to hurt:

```
read_files = glob.glob("post_stats_*.tsv") 
with open("result.tsv", "w") as outfile: 
    for f in read_files: 
        with open(f, "r") as infile: 
            metric_name = (f.strip(".tsv").split("_")[2]) 
            outfile.write(metric_name.upper() + "\n" + infile.read() + "\n")
```

Comment: Oh.. duh. Thank you!